# Non relationship model

Tags: laravel

Hi I have a model named AgencyBlocAgent and AgencyBlocGroup now AgencyBlocAgent has no relation with AgencyBlocGroup, it has one through relation AdvisorPortal model via User model

```
 public function portal()
  {
    return $this->hasOneThrough(AdvisorPortal::class, User::class);
  }
```

now in AgencyBlocAgent, I am getting the groups using the getGroupAttribute function
which is showing data fine initially,
but when I am trying order the data using group by of this group function it is returning null

```
public function getGroupAttribute()
  {
    $group_name = $this->getCustomFieldValue('Advisory Group Name');
    return AgencyBlocGroup::firstWhere('groupName', $group_name);
  }
```

how my question is how can I fix this issue I also sharing the paginate function, it is using to call the function

```
public function paginateModel(Model $model, Request $request)
  {
    if ($request->query('filter') !== null) {
      $model = $model::where('id', $request->query('filter'));
    }

    if ($request->query('order_by') !== null) {
      if ($request->query('sort_by') !== null) {
        // Explode the sort_by parameter
        $sort_array = explode('.', $request->query('sort_by'));

        // Extract the relationship and column name from the array
        $with = $sort_array[0];
        $column = $sort_array[1] ?? '';

        // If the column is set, we need to check the relationships between the models
        if (strlen($column)) {
          try {
            // If the model has a relationship with the `with` model
            if ($model::whereHas($with)) {
              // Get the primary model and it's table name
              $model = $model::with($with)->first();
              $model_table_name = $model->getTable();

              // Get the class name of the related
              $related = get_class($model->{$with});

              // Get an instance of the related model and it's table name
              $related = $related::first();
              $related_table = $related->getTable();

              // Get the 'singular' column name of the related and primary model
              $model_column_name = Str::singular($related_table);
              $related_column_name = Str::singular($model_table_name);

              // If the related model has a `model_name_id` array key then...
              if (array_key_exists("{$related_column_name}_id", $related->toArray())) {
                // dd('simple relationship');
                $model = $model::with($with)->orderBy($related::select($column)->whereColumn("{$model_table_name}.{$model_column_name}_id", "{$related_table}.{$related_column_name}_id")->take(1), $request->query('order_by'));
              } else {
                // dd('reverse relationship');
                $model = $model::with($with)->orderBy($related::select($column)->whereColumn("{$related_table}.id", "{$model_table_name}.{$model_column_name}_id")->take(1), $request->query('order_by'));
              }
            }
          } catch (Exception $e) {
            // dd('no relationship');
            $with = "get{$with}Attribute";
            if (method_exists($model, "get{$with}Attribute")) {
              $model = $model->orderBy($model->$with->orderBy($column), $request->query('order_by'));
            } else {
              dd('i dunno');
            }
          }
        } else {
          $model = $model->orderBy($request->query('sort_by'), $request->query('order_by'));
        }
      }
    }
    return $model->paginate((int) $request->query('limit') ?? 15);
  }
```

any help will be highly appreciated
thanks in advance